# Sum of nested arrays according to their indexes

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

If I have these corresponding array with 2 nested arrays (this may have 2 or more) inside:

```
const nums = [
    [4, 23, 20, 23, 6, 8, 4, 0],      // Each array consists of 8 items
    [7, 5, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0] 
];
```

How can I perform addition with them in accordance to their indexes ?

Expected Result:

```
// 11 is from 4 (array1 - index1) + 7 (array2 - index1)
// and so on.
[11, 28, 22, 25, 6, 8, 4, 0]
```

What I did was:

```
// This will work but it will only be applicable for 2 arrays as what if there will be 2 or more making it dynamic 

const total = Array.from({ length: 8 }, (_, i) => nums[0][i] + nums[1][i]);
```

Comment: Why `8 + null` is `7`? And what about `null + null`, the last one, why are you filtering that out? I mean, since `6 + null` is giving `6`, why `null + null` is not giving a `0`?

Comment: @Shidersz, sorry have updated the num list. Changed the null to 0.

Comment: @Shidersz https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This support n nested arrays

```js
const nums = [
  [4, 23, 20, 23, 6, 8, 4, 0],
  [7, 5, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [2, 1, 2, 5, 7, 8, 9, 4]
];


const total = nums.reduce((a, b) => a.map((c, i) => c + b[i]));

console.log(total);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This is quite short and straightforward :)

Comment: @MaheerAli Have you tested the code in the snippet? it works for both your mentioned cases, what am I missing here?

Comment: @MaheerAli this works with 3 or more, I have tested it on my end BUT I have a found small glitch just a small one and which it can be shorted with: nums.reduce((a, b) => a.map((c, i) => c + b[i])); and the 30 will appear - Have updated his answer as well since its his original idea

Answer (score 3):

One possible solution is to [Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) each element of the first inner array to the sum of elements in the same column. For get the summatory of elements in the same column we can use [Array.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) inside the `map()`:

```js
const nums = [
  [4, 23, 20, 23, 6, 8, 4, 0],
  [7, 5, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [1, 3, 4, 7, 1, 1, 1, 1],
];

let [first, ...rest] = nums;
let res = first.map((e, i) => rest.reduce((sum, x) => sum + x[i], e));

console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

Comment: @MaheerAli thanks for that generalization. However, in this case he mentioned all the arrays where of the same size: _Each array consists of 8 items_

Comment: @Shidersz Oh sorry didn't saw that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use nested `forEach()` loop

```js
const nums = [
    [4, 23, 20, 23, 6, 8, 4, 0],
    [7, 5, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0] 
];

function sum(arr){
  let max = Math.max(...arr.map(x => x.length));
  let res = Array(max).fill(0)
  res.forEach((x,i) => {
    nums.forEach(a => {
      
      res[i] = res[i] +  (a[i] || 0)
    })
  })
  return res;
}

console.log(sum(nums))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use reduce and an inner loop. Some of the things to be careful of are different array lengths & values that are not numbers.

```js
const nums = [
    [4, 23, 20, 23, 6, 8, 4, 0],      // Each array consists of 8 items
    [7, 5, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0] 
];
const otherNums = [
    [4, 23, 20, 23, 6, 8, 4, 0, 9, 55],      // Each array consists of 8 items
    [7, 5, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, "cat", null, 78],
    [7, 5, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, "dog", null, 78],
    [7, 5, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, "elephant", null, 78] 
];

const sumArraysByIndex = nums => nums.reduce((sums, array) => {
  for (const index in array) {
    if (sums[index] === undefined) sums[index] = 0
    if (isNaN(array[index])) return sums
    sums[index] += array[index]
  }
  return sums
}, [])

console.log(sumArraysByIndex(nums))
console.log(sumArraysByIndex(otherNums))
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the minimum length of `subarray` and then create the array of that length, using index return the addition.

```js
const nums = [
    [4, 23, 20, 23, 6, 8, 4, 0],
    [7, 5, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0]
];

const [arr1, arr2] = nums;
const min = Math.min(nums[0].length, nums[1].length);

const output = Array.from({length: min}, (_, i) => arr1[i] + arr2[i]);

console.log(output);
```

Comment: If I have these corresponding array with 2 nested arrays (**this may have 2 or more**)